# Customize VSCode new lines on save format

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm using vscode `format on save` feature and it was working great. but now it is forcing to insert a line break when using Square Brackets for arrays `[ ]` on objects. Like:

If I try to write this:

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "property": ["response"]   
  }
}
```

When I hit `Ctrl+S` to save, it formats the code to:

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "property": [
      "response"
    ]   
  }
}
```

And I don't want that for `[ ]`
I disabled every setting available relate to `add NewLine` for both `javascript.` and `typescript.`.  Any idea how to specify this?

Comment: Are you using a code formatter like Prettier in VS Code?

Comment: @Andy Nop. Just the "Auto format on save" from VsCode. Extension would be better?